# gensim installation on yosemite using anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, gensim

I've installed gensim on my MacBookPro (Yosemite 10.10.5 ) and I'm using anconda. The installation with `pip install --upgrade gensim` was working without error message. 
When I tried to run the code of the tutorials, there appears an error when calling serialization:
`corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('/temp/deerwester.mm', corpus)`

Complete error message:

`File "/Users/sage/Desktop/gensim/test_gensim.py", line 39, in <module>
    corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('/temp/deerwester.mm', corpus)
  File "/System/Library/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/gensim/corpora/indexedcorpus.py", line 94, in serialize
    offsets = serializer.save_corpus(fname, corpus, id2word, metadata=metadata)
  File "/System/Library/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/gensim/corpora/mmcorpus.py", line 49, in save_corpus
    return matutils.MmWriter.write_corpus(fname, corpus, num_terms=num_terms, index=True, progress_cnt=progress_cnt, metadata=metadata)
  File "/System/Library/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/gensim/matutils.py", line 486, in write_corpus
    mw = MmWriter(fname)
  File "/System/Library/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/gensim/matutils.py", line 436, in __init__
    self.fout = utils.smart_open(self.fname, 'wb+') # open for both reading and writing
  File "/System/Library/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 111, in smart_open
    raise NotImplementedError('unknown file mode %s' % mode)
NotImplementedError: unknown file mode wb+`

When I downloaded the tar files and performed `python setup.py test`,
the error `NotImplementedError: unknown file mode wb+` occurred too.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that files you've downloaded are for Mac? The error `NotImplementedError: unknown file mode wb+` may mean, that code you're using tries to open file in Windows [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: The error message I posted appeared after the installation with `pip install --upgrade gensim`. And after this I tried installing it from source with the tar file `gensim-0.12.3.tar.gz` from [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim]. But the error appeared again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an incompatability between `gensim` and the `smart_open` library.

I resolved the same issue (on a linux box) with

```
pip uninstall smart_open
```

`gensim` then falls back to using the filesystem directly, which was fine for me.